# Move the SharePoint site content to another SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint

I have an old site on a SharePoint server, the server is down and I didn't found any way to make it up again the windows update make the administration center give **cont connect to configuration database** error, so I decided to install a fresh WSS 3.0 on another server and move the content of my old site to a new site on the new server, the database name was WSS_AdminContent ... in fact I'm newbie to the SharePoint, so can any one tell me how to move the old content to the new WSS server, I don't know even how to make a new site which can accept this database, the databsae was containing a documents for my team !!!

thank you

Answer (score 4):

The basic steps are:

1. [Create a new web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954.aspx) in your new WSS server.
2. Follow the instructions in [Move content databases between instances of SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288554.aspx).

However you may not be able to perform all of the steps exactly as written if your previous server farm is not available. The main thing is that you get the most recent backup of the databases restored on your SQL Server, then follow these steps from the linked article:

> `13.` In Central Administration, on the Application Management page, in the
>   SharePoint Web Application Management
>   section, click Content databases.
>
> `14.` On the Manage Content Databases page, click Add a content database.
>
> `15.` On the Add Content Database page, type the exact name of the transferred
>   content database, and then click OK.
>
> `16.` Repeat steps 14 and 15 for each database you are adding. Be sure that
>   you select the correct Web application
>   from the Web Application menu for each
>   database.

I don't know your farm topology but if you are sharing the same SQL Server used for the dead server farm, make sure that the dead farm is completely powered off. You don't want two different SharePoint farms accessing the same data (especially if one is in an inconsistent state).

Comment: Thank a lot Alex - the lion ;) - I will try and tell you !

Comment: I created the web application and while creating my web application I selected my content database as the one I get from old server, and created a site collection under this web application, when I opened the site url I did not found any of my documents in my content databse !!!!

How can I get these documents ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new site collection. Once you've created the web application and attached the content database, your original site collection should be available. Check the 'Site collection list' link in Central Administration and choose your new web application from the drop-down in the top-right corner of the page.

Comment: Yes ... I found that I have a site collection actually, but when I goto its url it gives me file not found and this message
-------
File Not Found.

Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.  
---------

I don't know what dose it mean :(